# How to use Google fonts without internet connection

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to download Google fonts and link them offline on localhost web page?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq

Comment: You need to serve the font files and the CSS with `@font-face` definitions locally and add a `<link>` to those in you webpage. Bit of work, but not that hard to do...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for help
but i got it by help of this site https://transfonter.org/
then put all genereated woff files in same folder of css file then append font face to  my css file 
then use font normally as described by transfonter.org

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the font folder and add this to your projectFolder and use font faces.

Check this https://answers.themler.io/articles/9064/how-to-use-google-fonts-locally

Comment: I will try, I hope it success